# Having NaN as result instead of Error when trying to divide by 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am making a division in Pandas

```
db_new.loc[db_new['Business Model']=='CPV', 'Unit Cost (Media)']=db_new['Media Cost (Advertiser Currency)'] / db_new['Complete Views (Video)']
```

Rightly so, Python gives me error, since there are some zero at dividend:

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

How could I bypass this problem getting NaN or something like that instead of error?

Comment: What version is your `pandas`? Division by zero gives `inf` for me in `1.1.1`.

Comment: I don't know but it used to be like that when I used Jupyter locally, on google colab gave me this error. I installed the specific version of pandas you suggested thank you

Comment: @HenryYik My wild guess is that it also depends on numpy version as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do

```
V = db_new['Media Cost (Advertiser Currency)'] / db_new['Complete Views (Video)'].mask(db_new['Complete Views (Video)']==0)

db_new.loc[db_new['Business Model']=='CPV', 'Unit Cost (Media)'] = V
#db_new.loc[db_new['Business Model']=='CPV', 'Unit Cost (Media)'] = db_new['Media Cost (Advertiser Currency)'] / db_new['Complete Views (Video)'].mask(db_new['Complete Views (Video)']==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dividing, you can replace `0` with `np.nan`:

```
divisors = np.where(db_new['Complete Views (Video)']==0, np.nan, db_new['Complete Views (Video)'])

db_new.loc[db_new['Business Model']=='CPV', 'Unit Cost (Media)']=db_new['Media Cost (Advertiser Currency)'] / divisors
```